# convert text source into variable

Tags: php, variables, text

i have a **text result** from database like this:

```
var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3
```

How to convert into a variable and get the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = "var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3";


parse_str($str, $output);

print_r($output);


Array
(
    [var1] => value1
    [var2] => value2
    [var3] => value3
)
```

manual page:http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Ow...Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
<?php
$string = "var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3";
$string = explode("&", $string);

foreach($string as $key) {
    $result = strrchr($key,"=");
    $result = trim($result, "=");
    echo $result . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: sure but why would use it over the built in function?

Comment: I totally agree. I did not know about the built in function so I that's what I came up with. Thanks to you, I learned about the built in function. It's not something I ever needed but it's good to know :)